# Restrict features of iPhone app work for different app stores

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app that is on appStore.However this app gets some of the data from server side from an xml

My app is on different apple stores. However I want to restrict some features to only specific app stores. How can I make the application to work for different app stores , lets say make the app read different `xml` for different app stores or something like that? Is that possible? Or maybe Any place inside app where my app can read the store Type e.g find out if its USA Store or Japanese store or Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing this would be to have a input parameter in your API call which the application can request which country it's from, and then deliver your refined results based on that. Then, launch multiple apps in iTunes connect where each one specifies which country it is in the API request, and only allow it to be downloaded from that country.

For example, if you had two applications:

- MY APP (UK) - API call: http://example.org/api/uk/request.xml
- MY APP (USA) - API call: http://example.org/api/usa/request.xml

Note: The country you set in iTunes connect is the app store registered to the users account and not based on what country they are actually in!

Alternatively, you could use a online service to determine the location based on their IP. I haven't done this but a quick search finds:

- http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-find-ip-address-of-iphone/
- http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm?getlocation

Answer (score 0):

i think in you developer account in the app setting you can choose to which stores to upload, or do you mean like having different content for some stores?

Comment: actually disabling some features for some stores and enabling for others :) e.g i don't want to show a list in USA But i want to show that in England

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it in two ways:

1- build a different binary for each country

or

2 - find an API that let's you know what is the reference store for an user

About this second option, a quick search in the Apple documentation didn't return me a specific API to do this.
Sure, basing on the Locale is not good (what if the user changes the language settings?)

The only way I found is to use SKProduct class. It has a `priceLocale` property that returns an `NSLocale` instance. So if you do:

```
mySKProduct.priceLocale.localeIdentifier
```

you'll have a NSString with the locale associated to the reference AppStore. (in my tests: it_IT@currency=EUR ).

I tried it in a project with in app purchase enabled, I think that you must setup a real SKProduct to make it work properly

Regards
Fabio